# Rayleight Ritz Ratio and smallest eigenvalue for a set of given matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

I am familiar with Rayleigh Ritz Ratio for hermitian matrices. Let $A_1$ be a given $N \times N$ hermitian matrix. Then the smallest eigenvalue of $A_1$ is given by
\begin{align}
\lambda_{min}(A_1)=\min_{x^Hx=1}x^HA_1x
\end{align}
This led me to the following question. Let me define a new quantity 
\begin{align}
\lambda_{min}(A_1,A_2)=\min_{x^Hx=1}\max(x^HA_1x,x^HA_2x)
\end{align}
where $A_2$ is another given hermitian matrix. Is this quantity known before?. Is any there intuitive way of looking at it?

I was able to figure out that I could solve it using semi-definite optimization. Any comments on what happens when I try it for $k$ matrices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. But let me first modify the question by replacing the reals by the complex. Hence, $x$ runs over ${\mathbb C}^n$ and $A_1,A_2$ are Hermitian. Then $A_1,A_2$ can be viewed as the "real" and "imaginary" parts of a single matrix $M=A_1+iA_2$, that is
$$A_1=\frac12(M+M^*),\qquad A_2=\frac1{2i}(M-M^*).$$
The advantage of working within the complex numbers is that we know (Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem) that the image ${\cal H}(M)$ of the unit sphere of ${\mathbb C}^n$ under the numerical map $x\mapsto x^*Mx=x^*A_1x+ix^*A_2x$ is a convex compact subset of the complex plane.

Now, $\lambda_\min(A_1,A_2)$ (under the complex definition) is the minimum of the convex function $f(z)=\max(\Re z,\Im z)$ over ${\cal H}(M)$. We easily see that it is achieved on the boundary of ${\cal H}(M)$, at a point which is either the downmost point, or the leftmost point, or the most SW point along the diagonal $\Delta$ defined by $\Re z=\Im z$.

Specifically, we have the following alternative, where $x$ (resp. $y$) denotes some unit eigenvector of $A_1$ (resp. $A_2$) associated with $\lambda_\min(A_1)$ (resp.  $\lambda_\min(A_2)$) :

- either $x^*A_1x>x^*A_2x$, and then  $\lambda_\min(A_1,A_2)= \lambda_\min(A_1)$,
- or $y^*A_2y>y^*A_1y$, and then  $\lambda_\min(A_1,A_2)= \lambda_\min(A_2)$,
- or $x^*A_1x\le x^*A_2x$ **and** $y^*A_2y\le y^*A_1y$, and then $t:=\lambda_\min(A_1,A_2)$ is the number such that $(t,t)$ is the down-left point of the interval ${\cal H}(M)\cap\Delta$.

Comment: As a complement to Denis's approach, I think that joint numerical ranges could help to extend his alternative to $k$ matrices. See this paper, for example: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379503006797

Comment: @Denis Serre Excellent answer!! Thanks for that one. 

Comment: @Felix Goldberg, I will take a look at it. 

Comment: @Denis Serre Actually I had one more doubt, the image is closed convex compact set, does it mean, every point in it has a corresponding vector in the unit sphere which gives that point?

Comment: @dineshdileep. Yes indeed. This is a bit surprising, because ${\cal H}(M)$ is the image of a non-convex set (the unit sphere) by a nonlinear map (the numerical map). But this is the contents of the TH Theorem. Actually, this is a deep result, with many interesting consequences and relations. For an extension of this result, see my recent paper with Th. Gallay in CPAM **65** (2012), pp 287-336.

Comment: @Denis Serre This gives me some more doubts. Since I took the matrices to be hermitian, it means both of them can have negative eigenvalues. In this case, does it mean, there will be points in that convex set, such that both the co-ordinates are negative?. Thanks to you, I am seeing the deep impact of the theorem. 

Comment: @dineshdileep. If $A_1$ has a negative eigenvalue, ${\cal H}(M)$ has a point $w$ whose real part is negative. Likewise, if $A_2$ has a negative eigenvalue, ${\cal H}(M)$ has a point $z$ whose imaginary part is negative. From these facts, plus the convexity of ${\cal H}(M)$, you cannot conclude that it has a point with both coordinates negative. But of course, this will happen quite frequently. Example : if $M$ is normal, meaning that $A_1- and $A_2$ commute, then ${\cal H}(M)$ is just the convex hull of the eigenvalues of $M$: you see from the spectrum whether there is such a point.

Comment: @Denis I was reading more and more about numerical range. I found somethings hard to believe. Consider a single hermitian matrix $A_1$. So the image of the unit sphere will lie in the interval, $\lambda_{min}\leq x^HA_1x \leq \lambda_{max}$. So every irrational number in that interval will also come up for some non-zero $x$. But then how is that possible if $x$ and $A_1$ are not containing any irrational numbers. 

Comment: oh sorry, i just figured it out, $x$ should contain irrational entries in that case, isn't it?
